# Map<String, List<String>> to JSON using Gson

Tags: java, json, dictionary, serialization, gson

I didn't have any problems with using Gson before but now it looks quite strange. I'm trying to deserialize my object like this:

```
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
  new FileOutputStream(path), Charset.defaultCharset()))) {

    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    map.put("sun", new ArrayList<String>(){{
                            add("warm");
                            add("yellow");
                            add("luminescent");
                        }});
    map.put("tomato", new ArrayList<String>(){{
                            add("red");
                            add("tasty");
                        }});

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    writer.write(gson.toJson(map));

}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

which gives me an empty object:

```
{}
```

How to serialize and deserialize object like above properly?

Comment: GSON doesn't support anonymous classes. Initialize your lists normally and it will work.

Comment: Would you have expected a JSON object with "sunny tomatoes" instead (of the empty object), like: `{"tomato": ["red", "tasty"], "sun": ["warm", "yellow", "luminescent"]}`...?

Comment: @Dilettant yes, exactly what you wrote.